# Datapower Gatewayscript Urlopen MQ

Tags: ibm-mq, urlopen, ibm-datapower

How can I send message to the MQ manager with urlopen from gateway script?
I found this [example](https://github.com/ibm-datapower/datapower-samples/blob/master/gatewayscript/example-urlopen-mq.js).
But it doesn't work. I get an error:

```
mpgw (KSSH_MPGW_SC): URL open: Unsupported target 'dpmq://KSSH_MQQM_AC/?RequestQueue=rQ1' or protocol 'dpmq'
```

Does datapower support this opportunity?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use a slash after the MQQM object name. Could it be it ?

dpmq://KSSH_MQQM_AC?RequestQueue=rQ1

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your Firmware, dpmq:// from GWS is only supported after FW 7.2.

Answer (score 0):

Url open for MQ in datapower

```
var options = {
        target: dpmq://MQManagergroup/?RequestQueue=queuename,
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            "MQMP": MQMP
        },
        data: data in XML
    };

urlopen.open(options, function (Err, Resp) {

    if (Err) {
        throw new Err("URL open error." + JSON.stringify(Err));

    } else {


    }
});
```